# how to check and store data in mongo

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb

i am trying to store data in MongoDB.Here I am checking whether data is present or not. if data already exists then throwing an error or else storing data. please check the below code
in the below data having duplicate data(name and ICC). after saving the first record it should throw an error but here it's not throwing any error.

```
                    let Records = [{
                        name: 'test',
                        icc: 'testId'
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'test',
                        icc: 'testId'
                    }]
                    await Promise.all(Records.map(async (item) => {
                        try {
                            item['id'] = id
                            let ItemObj = table_name.build();
                            item.name = item.name;
                            item.icc = item.icc;
                            let found = await table_name.findOne({ where: { name: item.name, id: id } })
                            console.log("11111111111111111");
                            if (found) {
                                console.log("22222222222222222222");
                                throw new Error(item.name + " is already exist!");
                            } else {
                                console.log("333333333333333333333333333333");
                                Object.assign(ItemObj.dataValues, item);
                                console.log("4444444444444444444")
                                await ItemObj.save()
                                console.log("5555555555555555555")
                            }
                        } catch (err) {
                            throw new Error(err);
                        }
                    })
                    ).then((data) => {
                        console.log("final");
                    }).catch((err) => {
                        console.log("error logged");
                    })
```

here flow goes like
on console

```
                11111111111111111
                33333333333333333
                44444444444444444

                11111111111111111
                33333333333333333
                44444444444444444

                55555555555555555
                55555555555555555
```

Comment: ```item['id'] = id``` where is this ```id``` coming from?

Comment: id is coming from ctx.meta.fields.id[0]...

Comment: assuming that value of ```id``` is same for both items, your code should work as expected. Try to log ```found``` object, see what data is being saved in db.

Comment: when i log the found there it showing 'null'  both the times

Comment: i have given console.log 134 134 after this only its saving data

Comment: i think i understand the issue now. the first object is not saved by the time ```found``` is checked. can't you use ```for of``` loop?

Comment: actually, it saving the first and second time data...but the issue is after saving the first data in the second time the found = null ...i am not getting why its showing null.. can you plz help me to resolve

Comment: found null
found null

Answer (score -1):

Array of promise inside `Promise.all` get executed immediately, i mean it does not wait for first one to complete then move on to other. Imagine this as parallel execution (not actual working).

So keeping above analogy in mind, your `try` block for both item is getting executed simultaneously. When the `finOne` is executed for both items, none of them is saved so response is `null`

Comment: Thank you... i observed that in the console first two times findOne(Search query running ) after this insert query executed(2rrecords ) stored.